# sort data into existing clusters created by hclust() in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have performed a hierarchial clustering of matrices with `hclust()`. Now I have 5 clusters of which i would like to somehow save information so that at a later point I can define to which cluster given additional matrices (same dimensions) would fit the best.

I did this with kmean clustering before and used the minimal distance of the new data to any of these centroids. Is the same procedure recommended in this case and does it depend on the method(Ward etc.) ? Do you have any suggestions for improvement?

Answer (score 0):

It obviously depends on the parameters. Not just the linkage (Ward) but the *cluster mean* only works well for certain distance functions.

A more general approach is to use your initial clustering results (after verifying that it makes sense for your application, and maybe fixing a few misclustered points) as **training data for any classifier**. Then use the classifier to predict.